# ASP.NET Core 2.0 debuging on Rider

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, rider

1. I have project on ASP.NET Core 2.0, and working on it with Rider *(2017.2.1)*.
   I tried to debug it, but on error on Service creating or some errors in controllers action no any error fired on Rider, nothing happened, and I can not see where the error is, or why nothing happens...
2. If i clicked on use menu item to go to code on error I can not go direcly to string of code where error happends, nothing happened.
3. I can not see full text error (message + stack trace) on error, i need to copy it first ((.

Is this because Rider did not have full support of ASP.NET Core 2.0 debugging, and I just need to wait for a new version?

Comment: Try Rider 2017.3 EAP. If it still has problems in your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Dmitrij. Are you problem only in Debug launch? Could you try run your application and check it? The Rider should full support .NET Core debugging. Maybe you have any problems with restore packages?